# What would cause a SIGUSR1 to be uncaught by child thread that has a signal handler set?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I'm having something strange happen and I think it is probably me just not understanding the intricacies of threads in Linux.  I register a signal handler in my child thread with `signal(SIGUSR1, &callback)` and no special handling for signals in my parent thread.  At periodic intervals, my child thread raises a SIGUSR1.  However, it is causing an unhandled signal error in the main thread, which exits.  How can this behavior be reproduced?  When I try to reproduce with a test program, as long as the signal handler is set in the child thread, it always gets called for me.

Comment: I'm not being funny, but I'm not sure you should apply the concept of *parent* and *child* to threads - IMHO that is more applicable to forked **processes**. Threads are more like peers with access to the same address space and thinking of them like that might help avoid problems with understanding that signals can be delivered to any one of a set of peers rather than to a *parent* or *child*.

Answer (score 0):

Ooh, mixing signals and threads. That's not a great idea. If you must, have one thread as your signal handling thread and use pthread_sigmask() to mask all others. However if you are using SIGUSR1 as a form of inter thread communication, there are better ways to do that (mutexes and semaphores).

Comment: I understand that, but it does not answer the question.  I am under constraints as to how I can fix the problem.  Do you know what would cause this?

Comment: If you don't mask, the signal can be delivered to any thread.

Comment: Your comment is the answer.  Signals can be delivered to any thread that does not have a signal handler or signal blocked/masked.